# jsp update specific record on click

Tags: java, jsp

Hello i have a JSP page that displays records from animal table in my database which contain id, name, date-of-birth and some other information

what i want when the user click on animal name will be redirected to updateServlet which will display another JSP page for updating 
I was trying the following:

```
<td><a href="/Relay?update="+${view.animalId}>${view.animalName}</a></td>
```

where ${view.animalId} represents the animal_id column, and ${view.animalName} the animal_name and these records come from arraylist

is it possible to pass the animal_id in the link in jsp page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you were doing it wrong. You seem to think that HTML is a dynamic language and somehow part of the Java/JSP language. But this is not true. You should see JSP more as a HTML code generator. The following example should work for you:

```
<td><a href="/Relay?update=${view.animalId}">${view.animalName}</a></td>
```

This way it's as following available in the servlet mapped on `/Relay`:

```
String animalId = request.getParameter("update");
// ...
```